# Maps $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ finite with commutative algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a reduced, irreducible projective curve (=1D proper $k$-scheme) and $f \in k(C)$ a nonconstant rational function. The number of singular points of $C$ is finite, Assume that $f$ is contained in every local ring at each singular point, i.e. $f \in O_{C,c}$ for every singular $c \in C$.

Let $C_0:= C \backslash (\text{poles of }f)$. Define $A=H^0(C_0, O_{C_0})$.

Q: Why $A$ is a *finite* $k[f]$-module?

We can (at least I think that it's equivalent) rephrase the question to: Forget the curve stuff. Let $k$-algebra $A$ be an $1$-dimensional, Noetherian integral domain and $f \in A \backslash k$. Is $A$ is a *finite* $k[f]$-module?

The question is motivated by my [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354176/property-of-rational-functions-on-projective-curves) and the claim was found in proof of Lemma 1.20.5 from Janos Kolloar's Lecture on Resolution of Singularities (page 19) and is related to finiteness of nonconstant maps $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ as such maps are defined by rational functions.

The geometrical argument I'm familar with uses proper + quasi-finite => finite. Now I want to know if it possible to conclude that $A$ is a finite $k[f]$-module with pure methods from commutative algebra.

Comment: $k[f,f^{-1}]$ is not finitely generated $k[f]$ module.  I think it is the local-global principle: $k[C)/k(f)$ a finite extension, if $g\in k(C)$ is not integral over $k[f]$ then there is a discrete valuation of $k[f]$ which extends to $k(C)$ giving a negative valuation to $g$. Let $X$ be the smooth projective curve underlying $C$. Then $f\in k(X)$ and your condition $f \in O_{C,c}$ on the poles of $f$ and singular points of $C$ gives that $H^0(C_0,O_{C_0})$ is a subring of $O_X(X-poles(f))$ and the latter is integral over $k[f]$ because every discrete valuation of $k[f]$ extends to $k(X)$

Comment: @reuns: Your $X$ is the normalization of $C$, right? One point I not understand: you use this criterion with extendability of valuations to show that $O_X(X-poles(f))$ is *integral* over $k[f]$. Why does it imply that $O_X(X-poles(f))$ is *finite* over $k[f]$. "finite" implies "integral" but in general the other direction is wrong.